# Faster bit reading?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

In my application 20% of cpu time is spent on reading bits (`skip`) through my bit reader. Does anyone have any idea on how one might make the following code faster? At any given time, I do not need more than 20 valid bits (which is why I, in some situations, can use `fast_skip`).

Bits are read in big-endian order, which is why the byte swap is needed.

```
class bit_reader
{   
    std::uint32_t* m_data;
    std::size_t    m_pos;
    std::uint64_t  m_block;

public:
    bit_reader(void* data)
        : m_data(reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(data))
        , m_pos(0)
        , m_block(_byteswap_uint64(*reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(data)))
    {
    }

    std::uint64_t value(std::size_t n_bits = 64)
    {               
        assert(m_pos + n_bits < 64);

        return (m_block << m_pos) >> (64 - n_bits);
    }

    void skip(std::size_t n_bits) // 20% cpu time
    {
        assert(m_pos + n_bits < 42);

        m_pos  += n_bits;

        if(m_pos > 31)
        {
            m_block = _byteswap_uint64(reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(++m_data)[0]);
            m_pos  -= 32;
        }
    }   

    void fast_skip(std::size_t n_bits)
    {
        assert(m_pos + n_bits < 42);
        m_pos  += n_bits;
    }   
};
```

Target hardware is x64.

Comment: include some context, like what youre using this for.  Also, `using namespace std;`

Comment: I've a bit confused why you call `_byteswap_uint64` every 32 bits when it seems to swap 64 bits. Doesn't that mean you are calling it twice as frequently as you should?

Comment: @Wug: I'm deocing compressed data, such as JPEG files.

Comment: @jahhaj: Because I'm moving the `m_data` pointer 32 bits at a time and I have to have the correct byte order after each move.

Comment: @Wug: `using namespace std;` is not recommended. Source: Effective C++ by Scott Meyers

Comment: I disagree with that guy's opinion.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a matter of preference and is not on topic with the question.

Answer (score 2):

I see from an earlier comment you are unpacking Huffman/arithmetic coded streams in JPEG.

- `skip()` and `value()` are really simple enough to be inlined.   There's a chance that the compiler will keep the shift register and buffer pointers in registers the whole while.  Making all pointers here and in the caller with the `restrict` modifier might help by telling the compiler that you won't be writing the results of Huffman decoding into the bit-buffer, thus allowing further optimisation.
- The average length of each Huffman/artimetic symbol is short - so, ~7 times out of 8, you won't need to top up the 64-bit shift register.  Investigate giving the compiler a branch-prediction hint.
- It's unusual for any symbol in the JPEG bitstream to be longer than 32-bits.  Does this allow further optimization?
- One very logical reason that `skip()` is a heavy path is that you're calling it a *lot*.  You are consuming an entire symbol at once rather than every bit here aren't you?  There are some clever tricks you can do by counting leading 0 or 1s in symbols and table lookup.
- You might consider arranging your shift register such that the next bit in the stream is the LSB.  This will avoid the shifts in `value()`

Comment: 1. Would using `__declspec(noalias)` on `value` and `skip` have the same side effects as using `restrict`? 2. MSVC has unfortunately no such hint. 3. The maxiumum symbol length is 16bits. 4. I am consuming one symbol at a time. 5. I'm not quite following you on that one.

Comment: 1: This appears to operate at a function scope, but essentially seems to do the same thing.  What we want to do is hint to the compilers that direct writes to memory cannot write in places you read data from (the compiler has to assume that they do otherwise, resulting in additional loads into memory, and reduced optimisation opportunities).
MSVC does provide the `__restrict` modifier for use in variable declarations (in C it is `restrict` - so my bad)

2: Looks as though '__assume()' is what you want.

Comment: 4: Good! I did wonder whether you were taking bits at a time during decode.

5: In fact this should have been MSB rather than LSB.  I'm assuming you're using Huffman coding here? The way I have implemented this in the past is to peek the shift-register (e.g. provide an accessor to get m_block) determine the number of bits I want from it, then consume them. This is considerably cheaper when the shift register is maintained so that the next available bit is at one end or other.   You can then make use of intrinsics to find the first '0' or '1' (symbols typically have long runs one or other)

Answer (score 1):

Shifting for 64 bits is definitely not a good idea. In many CPUs shift is a slow operation.
I would advise you to change your code to a byte addressing. This will limit the shift for 8 bits maximum.

In many cases you really do not need a bit by itself, but rather to check if it is present or not. This can be done with a code like:

```
    if (data[bit_inx/64] & mask[bit_inx % 64])
    {
        ....
    }
```

Comment: I need `n_bits` number of bits from the `value` method.

Comment: Depends on the architecture.  On ARM it's ridiculously *cheap* to do shift-by-constant on 32bit words - they even come for free on the 3rd register in all arithmetic and binary operations.

Comment: Exactly. I was not stating that it is slow `on every` hardware platform.

Comment: I've always been told that shift was one of the fastest operations for x86 (except on Itanium)

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting this line in `skip`:

```
m_block  = (m_block << 32) | _byteswap_uint32(*++m_data);
```

Comment: Gives different result. Failed assertion,    `m_block  = (m_block << 32) | _byteswap_uint32(*++m_data);`   `assert(_byteswap_uint64(reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(m_data)[0]) == m_block);`

Comment: @ronag, that's because the `assert` comes after `m_data` has been incremented.

Comment: Yes? That's where it should be? My application failed when I changed the code to what you suggested, I added the assert to make sure.

Comment: @ronag, yes it's an off-by-one - in your constructor you should set `m_data` to `reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t*>(data) + 1`. Alternately you could change `*++m_data` to `(++m_data)[1]`.

Comment: @ronag, I hope you're doing the timing in release mode where the `assert`s are compiled out?

Comment: Why do you believe that your version would be faster? It is more instructions than the original?

Comment: @ronag it substitutes an aligned memory access for a possibly unaligned one, and does less byte-swapping. I thought it was worth a shot. At this level of optimization it's always a crap shoot, especially when you can't see the assembly generated by the compiler.

Comment: Actually I think your code could result in simply, `bswap` and `shld`. However the compiler does `bswap`, `shl` and `or` + some register moves. Unfortunately there is no intrinsic for `shld` in MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the cause and what the underlying implementation of _byteswap_uint64 looks like, but you should read [Rob Pike's article on byteorder](http://commandcenter.blogspot.de/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html). Maybe that's your answer.

Abstract: endianness is less of a problem than it's often made up to be. And the implementation for byte order swapping often come with issues. But there's a simple alternative.

**[EDIT]** I've got a better theory. Pasted from my comment below:
Maybe it's aliasing. 64 bit architectures love to align the data by 64 bits, when you read across alignment boundaries, it gets pretty slow. So it could be the `(++m_data)[0]` part, as x64 is 64 bit aligned and when you `reinterpret_cast` a `uint32_t*` to `uint64_t*`, you are crossing alignment boundaries about half of the time.

Comment: The byte swap is a single `bswap` instruction.

Comment: There goes my theory. But I've got a better one: Maybe it's aliasing. 64 bit architectures love to align the data by 64 bits, when you read across alignment boundaries, it gets pretty slow. So it could be the `(++m_data)[0]` part.

Comment: For a given CPU (x86 I assume?)

Comment: He said the target is x64, `m_data` is `uint32_t*`.

Comment: Yes, alignment could be an issue (and the code itself is rather confusing, each byte is kind of read twice each 32 bit step... it works, but is confusing when analyzing the code)

Answer (score 0):

If your source buffers are not huge, then you should pre-process them, byte-swap the buffers before you access them using the `bit_reader`!

Reading from your `bit_reader` will be much faster then, because:

1. you will save some conditional instructions
2. the CPU caches can be used more efficiently: it can read straight from memory, which is most probably already loaded into cpu cache, instead of reading from memory that will be modified after reading each 64bit chunk, and so, destroy the benefits of having had it in cache

**EDIT**

Oh wait, you do not modify the source buffer. However, putting the byteswap into a pre-processing stage should at least be worth a try.

Another point: make sure those `assert()` calls will only be in debug version.

**EDIT 2**

(deleted)

**EDIT 3**

Your code is definitely flawed, check the following usage scenario:

```
uint32_t source[] = { 0x00112233, 0x44556677, 0x8899AABB, 0xCCDDEEFF };
bit_reader br(source); // -> m_block = 0x7766554433221100
// reading...
br.value(16); // -> 0x77665544
br.skip(16);
br.value(16); // -> 0x33221100
br.skip(16);  // -> triggers reading more bits
              // -> m_block = 0xBBAA998877665544, m_pos = 0
br.value(16); // -> 0xBBAA9988
br.skip(16);
br.value(16); // -> 0x77665544
// that's not what you expect, right ???
```

**EDIT 4**

Well, no, EDIT 3 was wrong, but I can not help, the code is flawed. Isn't it?

```
uint32_t source[] = { 0x00112233, 0x44556677, 0x8899AABB, 0xCCDDEEFF };
bit_reader br(source); // -> m_block = 0x7766554433221100
// reading...
br.value(16); // -> 0x7766
br.skip(16);
br.value(16); // -> 0x5544
br.skip(16);  // -> triggers reading more bits (because m_pos=32, which is: m_pos>31)
              // -> m_block = 0xBBAA998877665544, m_pos = 0
br.value(16); // -> 0xBBAA --> not what you expect, right?
```

Comment: I cannot do it as a pre processing step due to the nature of the current algorithm, I'm reading 64 bit but stepping by 32 bit.

Comment: I would have to change to reading 32 bits which would mean I need to keep 2 32 bit m_blocks and use SHLD instructions to get the correct bits based on m_pos into a 32 bit m_block.

Comment: Byte swap ought to be very cheap, either being provided by a dedicated CPU instruction, or being an option on a load instruction.  is this what `_byteswap_uint32` results in?

Comment: `bswap` is a dedicated instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version I tried, which didn't give any performance improvements.

```
class bit_reader
{   
public:     
    const std::uint64_t* m_data64;
    std::size_t          m_pos64;
    std::uint64_t        m_block0;
    std::uint64_t        m_block1;


    bit_reader(const void* data)
        : m_pos64(0)
        , m_data64(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint64_t*>(data))
        , m_block0(byte_swap(*m_data64++))
        , m_block1(byte_swap(*m_data64++))
    {
    }

    std::uint64_t value(std::size_t n_bits = 64)
    {               
        return __shiftleft128(m_block1, m_block0, m_pos64)  >> (64 - n_bits);
    }

    void skip(std::size_t n_bits)
    {
        m_pos64 += n_bits;

        if(m_pos64 > 63)
        {
            m_block0 = m_block1;
            m_block1 = byte_swap(*m_data64++);
            m_pos64  -= 64;
        }
    }   

    void fast_skip(std::size_t n_bits)
    {
        skip(n_bits);
    }   
};
```

Answer (score -2):

If possible it would be best to do this in multiple passes. Multiple runs can be optimized and reduced breaching.

In general it is best to do

```
const uint64_t * arr = data;

for(uint64_t * i = arr; i != &arr[len/sizeof(uint64_t)] ;i++)
{
     *i = _byteswap_uint64(*i); 
     //no more operations here
}
// another similar for loop
```

Such code can reduce run time by huge factor

At worst you can do it in like runs of 100k blocks, to keep cache misses at minimum and single loading of data from RAM.

In your case you do it in streaming way witch is good only for keeping low memory and faster responses from slow data source, but not for speed.

Comment: I don't understand why you're suggesting this.   This loop is going to massive memory bound, whereas doing the swap in situ in `skip()` is going to come for free or nearly so.  In addition, you'd be passing over the bitstream data (remember: stuff we're highly unlikely to ever want again after decoding) twice.

Comment: Point is that you load 100k in cpu cache and then do operations without any branching. This cant have any memory bound. 
YOu can implemet this streaming that takes 100k of data it process them all and then just iterates over fixed data until more data is needed.